# User does not have permission to comment on this post

Tags: bug, comments

I got this error message trying to add a comment to [my own answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/239151/126) (to respond to a comment there). What gives?

Comment: Were you signed in? SE can randomly sign you out at times, it doesnt look like you have had problems commenting

Comment: Yes, I checked that specifically. I was signed in. It is working now though, so whatever.